# Error instalando composer con instalación manual de PHP en Windows 10

Tags: php, composer

Tengo una instalación manual de PHP y Apache en mi PC con Windows 10 usando los binarios.

Ya tengo colocado en el *path* la ruta.

Las carpetas tienen permisos de escritura y lectura.

Coloqué en `extension_dir` la ruta completa hacia `php.exe`, pero al tratar de instalar `composer` me da el siguiente error:

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or a dll does not exist.

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll' (tried: D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll (No se puede encontrar el mÃ³dulo especificado), D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el mÃ³dulo especificado))
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x86.dll' (tried: D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x86.dll (%1 no es una aplicaciÃ³n Win32 vÃ¡lida), D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x86.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el mÃ³dulo especificado))
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x86.dll' (tried: D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x86.dll (%1 no es una aplicaciÃ³n Win32 vÃ¡lida), D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x86.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el mÃ³dulo especificado))
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll' (tried: D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll (No se puede encontrar el mÃ³dulo especificado), D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el mÃ³dulo especificado))
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x86.dll' (tried: D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x86.dll (%1 no es una aplicaciÃ³n Win32 vÃ¡lida), D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x86.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el mÃ³dulo especificado))
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x86.dll' (tried: D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x86.dll (%1 no es una aplicaciÃ³n Win32 vÃ¡lida), D:\Programas\LocalServices\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x86.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el mÃ³dulo especificado))
```

Comment: Por los mensajes de error veo que estás mezclando DLLs de la arquitectura de 32 y 64 bits y, además, de los modos nts y el ts. ¿Qué binarios de PHP y Apache te has descargado? ¿Son ambos de 32 o 64 bits? ¿Son nts o ts? Cuando nos respondas a esas preguntas te podremos ayudar mejor.

Comment: Gracias a tu comentario pude trazar una ruta a mi solución, la cual era obvia pero no la había notado, eliminar las librerías de la arquitectura incorrecta y del modo nts el cual era incorrecto, muchas gracias por el aporte, me ayudo a solucionar el problema.